# Add-on UV Paste Copy/ Align Distribute and Screencast in Blender 2.72

Tags: add-on

I just installed the latest version (Blender2.72) - Add-on Screencast disappeared. I think it's a shame because it was very useful ... 
At a Blender 2.72 RC version I tested the add-on UV Copy/paste. And Align/Distribute UV. Blender on the site, they refer to these two add-on. But when I go to activate the Official, community testing and Blender 2.72 game. I can not find them. They have been removed as well? I thought it was official Add-On?

Comment: Screencast keys was removed because it has a lot of limitations.

Comment: See http://www.blendernation.com/2014/07/02/screencast-keys-addon-is-removed-b3d/ for some explanation. If you care to dig through the comments, there are some informative responses from the devs in there too. Here's a project to make a better replacement: http://jeh3.net/screencast-keys-status-addon-rewrite, however it seems to have some of the same limitations (they seem to be inherent to blenders python api)

Comment: Thank you for your answers and help. I managed to reinstall the add on screencast on the 2.72 release. I recorded the script .py and archive in zip file. The installation went without error and without limitation problem in using this add-on ... A friend possessing an i7 tells me that the add-on works well regardless of the views and / or renderer. This is cool :))

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about UV Copy/Paste addon, but Screencast have been removed indeed.
Still, there's nothing against using it, just install it manually - download source file and install from file:

[Screencast wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Screencast_Key_Status_Tool)

[UV Copy/Paste](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Copy_Paste_UVs)

Comment: Thank you for your answers and help. I managed to reinstall the add on screencast on the 2.72 release. I recorded the script .py and archive in zip file. The installation went without error and without limitation problem in using this add-on ... A friend possessing an i7 tells me that the add-on works well and all the view. Even in the renderer. This is cool :))